# Como ver datos de una tabla al dar click?

Tags: php, mysql

Ya estuve investigando y todo y no puedo encontrar como hacerlo, explico lo que quiero hacer...

Tengo esta tabla en PHP y MYSQL...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<table>
<thead>
     ...
</thead>
<tbody class="buscar1">
    <?php
    include("XXXXXXX/conexion.php");
    $sql = "SELECT *,
            COUNT(no_pedido) as ped,
            SUM(cantidad),
            SUM(precio_venta)
            FROM tblpedido INNER JOIN tblusers
            WHERE status = 'EN PROCESO'
            AND tblpedido.id_usuario=tblusers.id
            GROUP BY no_pedido";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;"> <!---- aqui quiero dar click ---->
            <i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg"></i> <?php echo $row['no_pedido']; ?>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['fecha_pedido1']; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['SUM(cantidad)']; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align: center">$ <?php echo $row['SUM(precio_venta)']; ?> MXN</td>
                ...
    </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    $result->free();
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Al dar click en numero de pedido1 me muestre en un modal todos los datos del pedido1 o al dar click en numero de pedido2 me muestre en un modal todos los datos del pedido2 ya si sucesivamente si tuviera más pedidos.

Los datos que quiero que me muestre en una tabla dentro del modal por ejemplo de pedido 1 o pedido2 en cada caso si doy click son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si me puedo explicar muchas gracias
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues yo lo resolvería usando javascript, más concretamente [jQuery](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

Empezaría añadiendo una clase a la imagen sobre la que quieres aplicar el evento. Por ejemplo, a esta clase la llamaremos 'npedido':

```
<td style="text-align: center">
    <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;" class='npedido'> 
    <i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg"></i> <?php echo $row['no_pedido']; ?>
    </a>
</td>
```

Posteriormente deberás trabajar con [eventos de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/). En este caso utilizaremos el evento **click()**

```
$('.npedido').on('click', function(){
    // Do something here
});
```

Con esto último lo que hacemos es aplicarle el evento click a todos los elementos que contengan la clase 'npedido'.

Ahora viene la chicha. Lo seguiente será realizar una llamada ajax a servidor para recuperar los datos que quieras mostrar. De esto hay muchísima información, así que te pongo varios enlaces que te serán útiles:

[Ejemplo llamada asíncrona .ajax](https://cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-ejemplo-paso-a-paso)

[Documentación .ajax de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

La llamada asíncrona deberás hacerla dentro del evento click, obviamente.

Por último queda pintar el resultado en una ventana modal. Como también hay muchísima información sobre esto, te adjunto algunos enlaces de interés.

[Ventanas modales con jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

[Ventanas modales sólo con css](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/crear-ventana-modal-solo-con-css3/)

[Ventanas modales con javascript, html y css](http://www.hinojosachapel.com/2008/11/como-hacer-una-simple-ventana-modal-con-html-y-javascript.aspx)

Como te he dicho, hay muchísima información y ejemplos en la red, sólo te he puesto tres de ellos.

Y con esto creo que no se me queda nada, tendrías todas las herramientas necesarias para poder hacer lo que quieres. Espero que te sirva y no dudes en preguntar cualquier duda.

Comment: Intente resolverlo asi como comentas investigue y todo pero soy nuevo en esto y no doy con la solucion lo unico que pude lograr fue.....Poner un querry con un while dentro del 1er while ya me muestra como lo quiero pero lo que deseo es que oculte todos los productos y al darle click al pedido me muestre eso que quiero ocultar

Comment: Lo siento pero ahora si que no entiendo muy bien que es lo que quieres hacer. En tu pregunta no comentabas nada de ocultar, y tampoco veo que tiene que ver ese **while** que comentas. Intenta explicar un poco mejor que es lo que quieres para así poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es que en el `href` del enlace, tomes el `id` de ese pedido y lo pases a otro **PHP** o dentro del mismo, a una variable:

```
<a href='my_php.php?mostrar=$dbId_producto'> //$dbId_producto es el identificador previamente obtenido al mostrar tu tabla de cada pedido.
```

Luego recibes ese `Id` y realizas la respectiva consulta `query` para que dentro de un `div` bien organizado, muestres los datos de cada pedido:

```
<?php
    $eId = $_GET['mostrar'];
    $db->preparar("SELECT no_pedido, id_producto, id_usuario, nombre_producto, unidad_producto, precio_venta, cantidad, fecha_pedido, fecha_pedido1, status FROM mytabla WHERE id_producto = ?");
    $db->prep()->bind_param('s', $eId);
?>
```

Espero haberte ayudado o darte una idea, es solo cuestión de lógica, ya el resto es diseño :)

Comment: Si lo habia intentado asi pero al momento de mostrar el DIV me muestra los mismos productos en todos los pedidos =(